# PostgreSQL enum table query returning [object Object]

Tags: sql, postgresql, enums

I have created (as part of a bigger database) an enum for another data structure as so:

```
CREATE TYPE training_days AS ENUM (
  'Monday',
  'Tuesday',
  'Wednesday',
  'Thursday',
  'Friday',
  'Saturday',
  'Sunday'
);
CREATE TABLE TrainingSlots (
  Day training_days PRIMARY KEY,
  Time VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
);
```

Whenever I insert data to this table and return it like so:

```
INSERT INTO TrainingSlots VALUES
    ('Monday','12:00'),
    ('Tuesday','12:00'),
    ('Wednesday','14:00'),
    ('Thursday','12:00'),
    ('Friday','12:00'),
    ('Saturday','15:00'),
    ('Sunday','16:00');
SELECT * FROM TrainingSlots;
```

I then get the output:

```
|             DAY |  TIME |
|-----------------|-------|
| [object Object] | 12:00 |
| [object Object] | 12:00 |
| [object Object] | 14:00 |
| [object Object] | 12:00 |
| [object Object] | 12:00 |
| [object Object] | 15:00 |
| [object Object] | 16:00 |
```

Why isn't the enum value being returned? Have I inserted the data wrong, or something like that?

Comment: i use pgAdmin and it works perfectly fine. What are you using?

Comment: @Aツ I'm using SQLfiddle

Comment: pasted your code in sql fiddle. the schema doesn't even build. why don't you try to use pgadmin with  your pg server?